# Using ISAPI_Rewrite 3 proxy over ssl

Tags: isapi-rewrite

Here is my rule:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.siteone.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^/checkout/(.*)$ https://www.sitetwo.com/checkout/$1 [NC,P]

What I am trying to do is use the checkout page on sitetwo to process an order related to siteone. Our overall plan is to have one checkout page handle orders from all our other websites and keep the website's url in the address bar. We need to do this to help with tracking click throughs, especially pay per click.

I have this rule working on our dev site where we don't use ssl.

Where are using IIS6

Siteone and sitetwo have their own SSL certificates. If I attempt to go to https://www.siteone.com/checkout/Default.aspx, I get an "Internal Server Error" show in the browser instead of going to the page.

Is there something we are missing in setting this up to work?

Thanks

Royal

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following syntax (if it's httpd.conf):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siteone\.com$ [NC]
RewriteProxy ^/checkout/(.*)$ https://www.sitetwo.com/checkout/$1 [NC,A,CR]
```